# Compare form values in react components at onSubmit or during changes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to compare 2 form components values like password and confirm password but it creates some problems.

Also suggest me to go with alert message or any new way to display the message that user will get some interactive message also.

When I put alert message in inputData function it always popping up and when I kept in submitData function it's not even checking it.

Here's my code:

```
 import React,{Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      password: '',
      c_password: '',
      isDone:false
    };
    this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);
    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
  }
  inputData(event)
  {
    if(this.state.password==this.state.c_password)
    {
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value,
        isDone:true
      });
    }
    else if(this.state.password!=this.state.c_password)
    {
        this.setState({
          isDone:false
        });
    }
  }
  submitData(event)
  {
    if(this.state.isDone==false)
    {
      alert("Passwords don't match")
    }
    else if(this.state.isDone==true)
    {
      alert("Passwords matched");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          Password:
          <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <input type="password" name="c_password" onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

When I execute it always shows don't match even if I write same password in both fields...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      password: "",
      c_password: "",
    };

    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
  }
  inputPassword = event => {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  };

  confirmPassword = event => {
    this.setState({ c_password: event.target.value });
  };
  submitData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { password, c_password } = this.state;
    const matches = password === c_password;
    matches ? alert("MATCHED") : alert("NO MATCH");  
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          Password:
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={this.inputPassword}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="c_password"
            onChange={this.confirmPassword}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

if you want to do it with one function
Declare byPropKey

```
 const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
  [propertyName]: value,
});
```

Now to use it the way you want.

```
<input value={this.state.password} onChange={event=> this.setState(byPropKey('password', event.target.value))} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input value={this.state.c_password} onChange={event=> this.setState(byPropKey('c_password', event.target.value))}
```

Comment: The way you created input and confirmPassword function, in that case I don't need to bind those functions??

Comment: no with es6 you can do `functionname = () => { ../code }` that autobinds it

Comment: I got whole of your code but still one question:

As I got all answer they all are setting values of both input tags in different function. What if I want to set the state in one single function?

Comment: its possible but it gets a little more complicated do you want me to show you or is this implementation sufficient?

Comment: Please, it would be really helpful to me. Because I'm making project and it contains a lot more props so it would not be good for me to make individual function for every input tag.

Comment: Failed to Compile:

> 16 |   const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
     |         ^
  17 |  [propertyName]: value,
  18 | });
  19 |

Comment: add that ontop of the class component it should not be inside render or inside the class it is global\ give me a moment

Comment: I tried to take it to top of component and also out of component. But when I keep at top of component shows same error and when I kept outside it removes error but input tags are not working.....

Comment: Are you sure it works, because when I open your link and write in first input tag it also write in 2nd input tag also by default and shows message no match....

Answer (score 0):

The above answer will work but we can do whole thing in one function. Also, we can utilise this function for many other fields. Initialize the `isDone = false` as default in the state.
Then answer for the above question goes like this:

```
inputData(event) {
const field = event.target.name

this.setState({
  [field]: event.target.value
})

if (this.state.password === this.state.c_password) {
 this.setState({
  isDone: true
 })
}
```

Tip:
1) You can use anonymous functions like `() => this.submitData()` in the  handler so that you don't need to bind the handler function with `this` in the constructor as this anonymous function preserves `this`.
2) For using forms efficiently you can use two popular libraries [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/) and [react-form](https://github.com/react-tools/react-form)

This will help you to get good errors as well as clear your code.